# Iphone SDK: How to center the TableCell text?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've a TableCell that creates other cells on push.

```
cell.text  = @"New note";
```

Everything's fine except for the text in the cell - I want it to be centered instead of alligned to the left.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;